# Import non-module vendor script in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, airconsole

I'm building an app with the [AirConsole](https://www.airconsole.com/) JS service. AirConsole only provides their library as a `.js` file you would include in your page with the usual:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.airconsole.com/api/airconsole-1.6.0.js"></script>
```

However, I'm using Webpack and would like to `import` the script into my other JS files. I have tried a few methods with no luck:

1. Create an entry file named `vendor` which imports the `airconsole.js` file. This creates a `vendor.bundle.js` file which I can include on my page
2. Add the AirConsole path to my `index` entry point so the script is included in the `bundle.js` file. With this method I can verify the AirConsole code is included in the `bundle.js` file but attempting to create a new instance of `AirConsole` results in `AirConsole` is undefined

Am I on the right track with these methods? If not, what is the recommended way to import a non-module `.js` file?

Answer (score 8):

The best way is by an action which we call "shimming". You can check out our new docs page for information. There are a few different ways to do on it (that depend on the needs) for your non-module.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/

Comment: Seems like I need the `script-loader` if I'm using [this file](https://www.airconsole.com/api/airconsole-1.6.0.js). When I try to create a new instance using `const airconsole = new AirConsole()` it throws a `undefined` error.

Comment: Also, does the `script-loader` work in the `webpack.config` or is it only intended for `require` statements.

Comment: Every loader you can use in your config (which is recommended) you can use the 'include' property to target a specific abs path of a file for the loader in config.